# Python Arithmetic sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to make an arithmetic sequence in python with the following code:

```
sum1 = 330(3 + 990)/2
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: "'int' object is not callable"
```

How should I do this correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
330(
```

Thinks you are trying to call a function on `330`, which is an `int`. If you're trying to multiply, it should be:

```
330 * (3 + 990)/2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for multiplication, the symbol to use is `*`:

```
sum1 = 330*(3 + 990)/2
          ^ THIS
```